# Android ViewFlipper keep the image still when startFlipping

Tags: android

I use viewFlipper in Android Eclipse. When the program call startFlipping(), the image will slide in from right to left. Therefore, everytime the startFlipping() is called after stopFlipping() then there will be a blank background.
What i want is when the startFlipping() is call, the image will remain still instead of swipe from right to left again.

This is my res/anim file

```html
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:interpolator="@android:anim/decelerate_interpolator">
   <translate
       android:fromXDelta="100%p"
       android:toXDelta="0"
       android:duration="500"/>
</set>
```

This is my xml file

```
     <ViewFlipper 
        android:id="@+id/flipper1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:flipInterval="3000"
        android:inAnimation="@anim/slide_in_right"
        android:outAnimation="@anim/slide_out_left">
         <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/main_background1"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:src="@drawable/space1"
                 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                 android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
          <ImageView
                 android:id="@+id/main_background12"
                 android:layout_width="match_parent"
                 android:layout_height="match_parent"
                 android:src="@drawable/space2"
                 android:adjustViewBounds="true"
                 android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

         </ViewFlipper>
        <Button
              android:id="@+id/start"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:text="Start" 
              android:onClick="startMethod"
              android:layout_gravity="bottom"/>

     <Button
         android:id="@+id/stop"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:onClick="stopMethod"
         android:text="Stop"
         android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
        />
```

This is my class file

```html
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        flipper1 = (ViewFlipper) findViewById(R.id.flipper1);

      //  flipper1.startFlipping();
    }

    public void startMethod(View view){
          flipper1.startFlipping();
    }

    public void stopMethod(View view){
          flipper1.stopFlipping();
    }
```

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

if you interlace the layout where the ViewFlipper. interlace the ViewFlipper into a linear_frame-layout, this linear/frame-layout shout be interlace into linearr_frame layout witch is the main-layout, follow:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8">
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="htt....>
<View android:layout_height="1dp" 
android:layout="fill_parent"     
android:background="#01Ff13">

<LinearLayout-thefirst..>
<you image here  />
</end from linearlayou-the first>

<Linearlayout-the second..>
<yourViewFlipper with the elements should animated../>
<end fromlinearlayout-thesecound/>

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: I think this is not what I asking for...but anyway thx for yor answer